# Java using uniVocity parser particular column data has comma and its not enclosed

Tags: java, csv, univocity

I am mostly using uniVocity as a CSV parser, its a excellent parser. I have hit below problem with below rows, this file will have fixed number of 7 columns. The problem is with client name, it can have commas, the next column to it Type, it is generally S or P.

Below is the test data,

```
Date,Code,Company,Client,Type,Quantity,Price
03/03/2014,500103,BHEL,PoI THROUGH DoI, Affairs,S,114100000,165.55
21/04/2017,533309,DALMI,KKR MAURITIUS CEMENT, LTD.,S,106020,2050.00
21/04/2017,533309,DALMI,KKR MAURITIUS CEMENT, LTD.,P,141740,2050.00
```

Above data has problem with Client name because data itself has comma and its not enclosed. below are the client names

```
PoI THROUGH DoI, Affairs
KKR MAURITIUS CEMENT, LTD.
KKR MAURITIUS CEMENT, LTD.
```

Could you please let me know how to handle it

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't really do a lot here if the data doesn't come enclosed with quotes. All you can realistically do is to check the row length and if it is greater than 7 you know that the extra columns are part of the client name.

Here is my solution:

```
for (String[] row : rows) {
        if (row.length > 7) {
            int extraColumns = row.length - 7; //we have extra columns
            String[] fixed = new String[7]; // let's create a row in the correct format

            //copies all data before name
            for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < row.length; i++, j++) {
                fixed[j] = row[i]; //keep copying values, until we reach the name

                if (i == 3) { //hit first column with a name in it
                    for (int k = i + 1; k <= i + extraColumns; k++) { //append comma and the value that follows the name
                        fixed[i] += ", " + row[k];
                    }

                    i += extraColumns; //increase variable i and keep assigning values after it to position j
                }
            }
            row = fixed; //replaces the original broken row
        }

        //prints the resulting row, values in square brackets for clarity.
        for (String element : row) {
            System.out.print('[' + element + ']' + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This produces the output:

```
[Date],[Code],[Company],[Client],[Type],[Quantity],[Price],
[03/03/2014],[500103],[BHEL],[PoI THROUGH DoI, Affairs],[S],[114100000],[165.55],
[21/04/2017],[533309],[DALMI],[KKR MAURITIUS CEMENT, LTD.],[S],[106020],[2050.00],
[21/04/2017],[533309],[DALMI],[KKR MAURITIUS CEMENT, LTD.],[P],[141740],[2050.00],
```

Hope it helps.